# Why is outer measure called outer?

Tags: measure-theory

Why is outer measure called outer?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OuterMeasure.html

Is it because the $\inf$ in

$$\mu^* (E)=\inf \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k)$$

Takes the smallest bound for all the measures? So in that sense it can be thought to give the "(outer) bound" for the measures?

Comment: It is called "outer" because you are taking the measure of sets that cover $E$, so you are "approximating $E$ from the *outside*" with measurable sets.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff That doesn't sound intuitive. I thought the measure of sets that cover $E$ are "contained in" $E$ so they're not outside of $E$ so they don't sound like they can approximate $E$ from the outside. Rather perhaps you mean that one "fills in" $E$ so that one attains the outer measure of $E$?

Comment: You are taking sets $E_k$ such that $E \subseteq \cup E_j$. The measurable sets I am talking about are these unions. Note however that the $E_j$ are not assumed to be contained in $E$ in the definition.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Aha now I see, I thought that the $E_j$s are inside $E$.

Comment: It would help if textbooks that mention "outer measure" would also mention (at least in a footnote) the parallel notion "inner measure". Indeed, I believe for the first decade or so (and definitely in Lebesgue's original 1902-1903 initial work on Lebesgue measure) that both notions were used in defining "measurable set" (one in which its inner measure is equal to its outer measure --- like limit exists if and only if lim-inf = lim-sup).